# Connecting older version of mongo with python

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am using pymongo module to connect to remote mongo DB. It works fine for me for all the latest versions but for older versions I am getting an error as below can you help me out how to connect older version of mongo with python using pymongo or any other way.

The error is shown as below:

**Server at XXXXX:20001 reports wire version 0, but this version of PyMongo requires at least 2 (MongoDB 2.6).**

Answer (score 0):

you are using pymongo and mongodb has some dependent informations about versions, so check if your driver will support that mongodb Ecosystem or not

as follow the link https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/python/

Comment: Yes the doc also says that pymongo drivers don't support the older mongo versions but in that case how to connect python to older mongo versions??

Comment: i don't know exact way for you question but you have to  install python for which mongodb will support in which version of your's. it will clearly explain in mongo Ecosystem.

Comment: example python-3.6 will supported only below of the mongodb 3.6 versions earlier  version does not. in that way you have to install specific version in your system.